# Finding an element within an array that contains an array with a given string: JsonPath Java

Tags: jsonpath

I'm new to JsonPath and am using the Java port https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath.

I have a JSON object that looks like this (there are actually many entries, but I have removed the additional entries for brevity).

```
{
    "entry": [{
        "fullUrl": "urn:uuid:42627ef0-ea02-4323-8059-c8dfb6125314",
        "resource": {
            "resourceType": "Patient",
            "id": "42627ef0-ea02-4323-8059-c8dfb6125314",
            "meta": {
                "profile": [
                    "http://hl7.org/fhir/us/mcode/StructureDefinition/mcode-cancer-patient",
                    "http://hl7.org/fhir/us/core/StructureDefinition/us-core-patient"
                ]
            },
            "text": {
                "status": "generated",
                "div": "<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">Generated by <a href=\"https://github.com/synthetichealth/synthea\">Synthea</a>.Version identifier: v2.5.0-340-gabc9fc4a\n .   Person seed: -7528621318134299240  Population seed: 1586172373839</div>"
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

I am trying to find an entry that contains a specific URI within the profile array. I cannot seem to get the correct syntax for this to work properly and am a bit stumped at this point.

Here is what I have tried so far, without success.

```
$..entry[?(@.resource.meta[?(@.profile.indexOf('http://hl7.org/fhir/us/core/StructureDefinition/us-core-patient') > -1)])]
```

Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jayway Jsonpath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#jayway-jsonpath) implementation  doesn't support `indexOf`. use `in` instead.

```
$..entry[?('http://hl7.org/fhir/us/core/StructureDefinition/us-core-patient' in @.resource.meta.profile)]
```

Please refer [Filter Operators](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-operators) supported by Jayway jsonpath

Online Test Tool : https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/